# HSQLDB connection throws SQLException and HsqlException at the same time

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm doing an app for my high school and I have the following situation:

I will use an embedded HSQL database for storing my application data. When I open the connection, I try to connect to the database only if exists, so it will not be created if it doesn't exist. Basically, if an HsqlException is thrown, functions to create the database, tables and constraints will be called.

The point is that this line:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
```

Throws an SQLException AND an HsqlException. But if I try to catch and control them, the output keeps being like this:

```
run:
2014-11-19T20:15:25.142+0100  SEVERE  could not reopen database
Catched an Hsql or SQL Exception. //This is my 'control' over the Exceptions.
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: La base de datos no existe: C:/Databases/DB
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at DBManager.DBManager.main(DBManager.java:20)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

And finally this is my code. I hope someone call tell me why is this happening.

```
package DBManager;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBManager {
    static Connection c;
    static Statement stm;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {

            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Databases/DB;create=false", "SA", "");         

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException has been catched.");
        } catch (SQLException | org.hsqldb.HsqlException ex) {
            System.out.println("Catched an Hsql or SQL Exception.");
            //TODO call connection where the database is created.
            //TODO create schema CreateSchema.run(c);
            //TODO create constraints
        } finally {
            //TODO
        }
    }


   private static class CreateSchema{
       public static void run(Connection con){
           //TODO: Create table queries.
       }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not already have a HSQLDB database in C:/Databases/DB then this is behaving how I would expect. Your connection string tells it not to create the database if it does not exist, so it can't return an exception so it throws an exception which you are catching and logging.

Because the exception has been caught the run is considered successful because the main method did not throw an exception or call System.exit() with a non-zero value.

The exception you are catching is actually the SQLException and not the HsqlException (which is a RuntimeException) - the SQLException has a nested HsqlException. If you print the stack trace of the exception (`ex.printStackTrace()`) you can see this. So you should just catch SQLException.

The extra output you see is from within the HSQLDB driver class - if you look at the source for `org.hsqldb.Database#reopen()` you can see it calls `logger.logSevereEvent("could not reopen database", e);` and that's what responsible for the extra output you see. It tries to use a logging framework if one is available and defaults to the one in the JDK, which if not configured will print to System.err.

Comment: I tried to use a Logger with a custom ConsoleHandler
    `public class MyHandler extends ConsoleHandler {

    public MyHandler() throws FileNotFoundException {
        setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("log.txt")));
        }
    }`
And then in `DBManager` use it creating a `static final Logger = Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class.getName());` and before the first `try` of the `main` method, I put this `  logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);` and I add an instance of MyHandler with `logger.addHandler(Handler h)`. File "log.txt" but nothing is printed. How can I continue?